# How to apply transaction logic to non database actions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, system-calls

I have a form in a view that has an input box. If you fill in the input box and press "Save", a system command is executed and the value is persisted to the database.

I check If the command has executed successfully and then, If the value has been updated to the database. What I don't do is to run them both in some kind of a "transaction" so the change is complete If both the `"system_command == true"` and the `.update == true`.

Probably the nested conditionals is a wrong thing to do because If the `.update` fails, the system command has been executed already and cannot be reversed.

```
  def update
    if system_command # Checks If command was executed successfully
      respond_to do |format|
        if @system_command.update(system_command_params)
          format.html { redirect_to system_commands_path, notice: 'Success' }
        else
          format.html { render :index }
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_to system_commands_path, notice: 'Failed'
    end
  end
```

**system_command** is a method that executes a system command.

How could I be 100% sure about the integrity of this method's actions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can validate your record before saving it:

```
@system_command.assign_attributes(system_command_params) # Assign params, but don't save.

# `system_command` will only be run if the @system_command passes Rails validations.
if @system_command.valid? && system_command
  @system_command.save
  # ...
end
```

Note that native DB constraints will not be considered when calling `valid?`

Comment: So actually you check your params against the database to see If it validates? But there are two cases here: (1). Is .save the same as .update ?  and (2). You save the data to the db If the validation returns true and the system_command will have already made those changes.

Comment: Almost, `.update` assigns the attributes from the hash that's passed and saves the record if it's valid in one step. It seems like you have a chicken-and-egg problem. Should `system_command` run first, or the database `save`? It has to be one or the other. It's impossible to say without knowing what `system_command` is doing. Can you sandbox it or run it in a subshell so you can rollback?

Comment: Exactly, a chicken-and-egg problem is what it seems to be. The good thing is that I am doing a lot of tests for the `system_command` so in the end I am pretty sure If it fails or not. So there's no point to save to db If the `system_command == false`. On the other hand, If `system_command == true` and then the db .update fails, I can't roll back the system command actions. Or If I did, the project would double in size. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Maybe I could create a transaction for the db .update and insert the system_command inside the block. What do you think ?

Comment: That's not going to work, transactions are specific to applying updates and inserts to databases. They don't affect control flow or any logic within Ruby.

Comment: But there's the possibility to add a begin rescue end block and enter the system command there. So If it raises an exception, the ActiveRecord will Rollback the changes. I believe it's the safest.

Comment: I think you may be confused on how ActiveRecord works. If you call `valid?` before saving, as in my example, then you wont have a failure on `update` unless the db is updated by another thread which invalidates the validation (e.g. perhaps a record of the same value gets created which triggers the uniquess constraint -- so you may as well use a transaction), or you violate a constraint at the db level, outside of Rails. Both cases are pretty easy to avoid. So you can know ahead of time if `update` will fail, but you don't know if the command itself will fail without knowing its result.

Comment: Point is, you need a way to run the command in an idempotent fashion. Hard to say without having more information about what the command does. In any case, you should really avoid running shell commands from your controller if at all possible. If you do need to run shell commands, make sure they are running in a protected environment, preferably in a sandbox like Docker.

Comment: I don't want to use docker for this kind of problem, at least for now. Please take a look at my answer below and let me know what do you think. * I also will have to rollback the system_command change in the rescue part.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this solution works but I am not able to test it yet.

```
  def update
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @system_command.update(system_command_params) # Update the db
      begin
        system_command # Run the command
        redirect_to system_commands_path, notice: 'Success' 
      rescue # If the command fails
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        redirect_to system_settings_path, notice: 'Fail'
      end           
    end
  end
```

Comment: I don't see what advantage this has vs. my answer above, since in my example the record won't be saved unless the command succeeds. The transaction wrapper makes some sense, however, your exception handler isn't really doing much here. `system_command` is a shell script right? If so, it will error outside of Ruby and not trigger the `rescue`. The syntax here is also `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback`)

Comment: system_command will return true or false after completion or failure. I could raise an exception for this.

Comment: In my example, `if @system_command.valid? && system_command` will only evaluate to true and save the record to the database if the `@system_command` record is valid AND the `system_command` method returns true. What advantage does this approach have?

Comment: Doesn't ActiveRecord::Base.transaction have more integrity than simple commands ?

Comment: I mean building the transaction logic "manually" instead of using automated and tested ActiveRecord methods like .transaction ? But however, this is not the case 100%. Some of the problems still remain and it seems to me that it can't be solved in any other way than writing a rollback function for the system commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111117/discussion-between-anthony-e-and-chris-v).